# selecting from multiple tables with order and group

Tags: php, mysql

i've been having this issue for along time couldnt find a solution, 
i need to select from multiple tables using union to select ids and then sort results by date, i have made this query (and it used to work in older mysql versions)

```
(SELECT MAX(id),UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) AS date,stock_id, 'Purchase' as type FROM stock_entries WHERE type='entry' GROUP BY stock_id)
                UNION
                (SELECT MAX(id),UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) AS date,stock_id, 'Sales' as type FROM stock_entries WHERE type='sales' GROUP BY stock_id)
                UNION (select id,date, `order` AS stock_id, 'Inventory' as type FROM inventory_trans)
                ORDER BY date ASC
```

What i want is , i generate one ID each time, and also one type, type is either Purchase or sales or Inventory , and all results should be sorted by date (older --> newer) from both two tables , whenever i run the above query i have this error :

```
1140: In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #3 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'system.inventory_trans.order'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

How to phrase this SQL query to get me exactly what i need based on date frame (Date ASC) -- older results --> newer results

Thank you

Comment: Consider providing proper CREATE and INSERT statements AND a desired result.

Comment: the output each time should be something like id==>5, type is Purchase , date=>12232434 (unix time) , next loop , id=>9,type is Sales, date=>122343434 and so on , id=>10,type is Inventory, date=>122343454, ...  based on date when Purchase or Sales, Or inventory happened  which is stored in each table.

Answer (score 0):

please give this query a try.

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT s.id,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(s.date) as date,s.stock_id,
       M.newType AS type
   FROM stock_entries s
   INNER JOIN
     (SELECT MAX(id) as maxid, stock_id,IF(type='entry','Purchase','Sales') as newType
      FROM stock_entries
      WHERE type='entry' OR type='sales'
      GROUP BY stock_id,newtype) as M
   ON M.maxid = s.id 
   )T1   
UNION ALL
  (select id,`date`, `order` AS stock_id, 'Inventory' as type FROM inventory_trans)
ORDER BY date ASC
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cb5b4/9)